# Functional Derivative with Discrete Variable

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, functional-calculus

## Problem

$$\text{Find}\quad\frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G} \quad \text{given} \quad F_k=\left(\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{ikr}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \ e^{i\omega t} G(r,t)\right)^{-1}$$

noting that $k$ and $r$ are discrete while $\omega$ and $t$ are continuous.

## Background

I am trying to show that $F_k[G(r,t)]$ is very sensitive to perturbations in $G(r,t)$. By numerical work I know this is (often) the case. Ultimately I'd like to argue that constructing $F_k$ by measuring $G(r,t)$ won't work well when the measurement is noisy. I figured a good way to show that was to compute the functional derivative and show it gets large (or perhaps diverges) in some places. However, I am doing something wrong.

## Attempt

By the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Definition):

$$\frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}:\int dt \frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}\eta(t)=\left[\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{ikr}\int dt \ e^{i\omega t} G(r,t)+\epsilon\eta(t)\right)^{-1}\right]_{\epsilon=0}$$

Using the chain rule, $\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{ikr}=N\delta_{k,0}$ i.e. the Kronecker delta, and the definition $G(k,\omega)\equiv\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{ikr}\int dt \ e^{i\omega t} G(r,t)$ transforms the above to

$$\frac{-\int dt\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{i(kr+\omega t)}\eta(t)}{\left(\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{ikr}\int dt \ e^{i\omega t} G(r,t)\right)^{2}}=\int dt\frac{-\delta_{k,0} \ e^{i\omega t}}{G(k,\omega)^2}\eta(t)\to \frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G(r,t)}=\frac{-\delta_{k,0} \ e^{i\omega t}}{G(k,\omega)^2}$$

I know this is wrong because this numerics show this isn't $0$ for all $k\neq 0$. I suspect the problem has something to do with $\eta$ only depending on $t$ and not $r$, but I'm not sure how to account for a discrete variable like $r$.

## Resolution?

I think my understanding of the definition above is likely wrong, and probably needs a test function that depends on both $r$ and $t$? I'd be pretty jazzed if the right way to do it looked something like

$$\frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}:\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\int dt \frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}\eta(r,t)=\left[\frac{d}{d\epsilon}F_k\left[G(r,t)+\epsilon\eta(r,t)\right]\right]_{\epsilon=0}$$

but my math is too weak to assert this is the right way, even though it looks like it makes some sense (to me). I really have no idea how to handle the fact that $r$ is discrete. If the above is correct, this would give

$$
\frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G(r,t)}=\frac{-e^{i(\omega t+kr)}}{G(k,\omega)^2}
$$

which is what I was hoping to show since $G(k,\omega)=0$ for at least one $\omega$ at every $k$.

## Seeking

Any of the following

1. $\dfrac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}$
2. How to approach such functional derivatives?
3. What's wrong with my attempt?
4. Confirm/deny the correctness of my "resolution".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you clarify what the summation variable is? also from the very beginning only one term has $k$ in it, which allows you to rewrite before you take the derivative. Sounds like this is not what you intended?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am not sure I follow. I am summing over $r$ so that $F$ is a function of $k$. Since $G$ is a function of $r$, I don't think this becomes trivial?

Comment: Well that was one way to answer my question. What you mean is, by $\sum_r^N$ you mean $\sum_{r=\dots}^N$ where $\dots$ is presumably 0 instead of say $-17$? With so many variables, omitting details is confusing

Comment: if there is still a nontrivial function of $r$, how can you apply the identity $\sum_r e^{ikr} = \delta_{\text{something with no r}}$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ah I see. I have updated the post. If it helps this is a Fourier Transform from position space to momentum space for a finite lattice, so $k=2\pi n/N$ for $0\leq n<N$. If that doesn't help just ignore it. I can apply the identity there because $G(r,t)$ isn't present.

Comment: Oh, i see that’s because you’re considering perturbations that do not depend on $r$ as you mentioned. I don’t see anything wrong with your ‘resolution’, having stumbled (sorry) through the post. The functional derivative of your functional $J:X\to\mathbb C$ should take perturbations from $X$, in this case, $r$ dependent functions

Comment: @CalvinKhor, you say you don't see anything wrong with my "resolution" but I kind of just pulled it out of nowhere. Do you know if there's a way to justify/derive it? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, the resolution comes by correctly applying the definition of a functional derivative, cf last sentence of my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer to your questions not in their former order, in order to possibly answer in a better way.

> 2. How to approach such functional derivatives?

The approach you adopted (though with some slips as we'll see below) is the correct one, i.e.
$$
\frac{\delta F_k }{\delta G}[G](\eta) \triangleq DF_k[G](\eta) \triangleq \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d \epsilon}} F_k(G+\epsilon \eta)\right|_{\epsilon=0}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
The calculations have to be done as the right hand were a function of the real variable $\epsilon$: the definition does not depend on how the functional $F_k$ acts on its argument $G(r,t)$, thus is irrespective of the discreteness and / or the continuity of the involved variables. We'll see below that the *discreteness* and *finiteness of the values* of the variable $r= 0, 1, \ldots, N-1$, in this particular case, can be efficiently dealt by representing the argument $G$ and the variation $\eta$ as vectors in an $N$-dimensional space, but this is by no means implied by the structure of equation \eqref{1} itself.
The structure of functional derivatives is illustrated in some detail in [this Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584): for the reasons given there, you'll see that it is not safe to trust the Wikipedia entry on the topic.

> 3. What's wrong with my attempt?

The main slip which is usually done (as in [this case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354919/the-derivative-of-a-filter-with-respect-to-a-output-singal/) and in [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807224/nonlinear-functional-variational-calculus)) is to expect that this kind of derivative has the structure of a function: it is almost never so. Customarily, *functional derivatives are operators* that map a variation $\eta$ of the argument $G$ of the functional to the variation of the corresponding value of the functional itself. Answering more extensively this point of the question question,

1. you are considering variations of the single $t$ variable: this is not an absolute error, since you can licitly do so if you are sure that the input function $G=G(r,t)$ cannot change its value "randomly" if the discrete variable $r$ is kept constant. However, since you are trying to analyze the performance of $F_k$ on noisy inputs, you should consider the possibility to have $\eta=\eta(r,t)$ for $r=0, 1,\ldots,{N-1}$, and
2. you expect the functional derivative to be a function, while it is an integral operator: seeing this will help you in evaluating the variation of your functional when subjected to noisy inputs.

> 1. $\dfrac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}$

Formally, by putting
$$
\begin{split}
&\mathbf{r} =(0, 1, \ldots, {N-1}),\\ 
& e^{ik\mathbf{r}} =\big(1, e^{ik}, \ldots, e^{ik{(N-1)}}\big), \\
& \eta(\mathbf{r}, t) =\big(\eta(0,t), \eta(1,t), \ldots, \eta({N-1},t)\big),
\end{split}
$$
we can write the functional derivative of $F_k$ as
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta F_k}{\delta G}[G](\eta) &= DF_k[G](\eta)\\
 & =-\frac{{1}}{G(k,\omega)^2}\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{ikr} \int \eta(r, t)\;e^{i\omega t} \mathrm{d}t\\
 & = -\frac{{1}}{G(k,\omega)^2} \int \left\langle e^{ik\mathbf{r}}, \eta(\mathbf{r}, t)\right\rangle e^{i\omega t} \mathrm{d}t
\end{split}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle:\Bbb R^N\times\Bbb R^N \to\Bbb R$ is the ordinary scalar product. By using equation \eqref{2} and a suitable choice of the variation $\eta(r,t)$, you will be able to analyze the sensitivity of $F_k$ to particular variations of its argument function $G$.

> 4. Confirm/deny the correctness of my "resolution".

Your resolution is "almost correct" in the sense that, after performing correctly the derivative, you should chose a suitable variation $\eta(\mathbf{r}, t) =\big(\eta(0,t), \eta(1,t), \ldots, \eta({N-1},t)\big)$ in order to get your result. And obviously your choice should be consistent with the problem you are dealing with.